# How to make a Table resizable in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

In my UI, there is a webView and below that is a table to record some actions in the webView. They are placed one below the other. I want the table below to be resizable. The table is fixed to left, right and below borders. User should be able to drag it up. Just like the inspect element opens up a window below the browser and user can drag it up to view more content.

How can I do this in JavaFX? Please help.

Update:
I tried the below:

```
HBox.setHgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);
VBox.setVgrow(table, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

None of them had any effects. In scenebuilder, I'm binding the table to bottom, left and right borders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.web.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="720.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.controller.RecordController">
   <children>
      <WebView fx:id="webView" layoutX="80.0" layoutY="48.0" prefHeight="204.0" prefWidth="720.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="156.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="40.0" />
      <TableView fx:id="table" editable="true" layoutY="244.0" prefHeight="156.0" prefWidth="626.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
         <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="stepDescription" prefWidth="152.0" sortable="false" text="STEP DESCRIPTION" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="stepType" prefWidth="85.0" sortable="false" text="STEP TYPE" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="pageName" prefWidth="86.0" sortable="false" text="PAGE NAME" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="objectName" prefWidth="102.0" sortable="false" text="OBJECT NAME" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="actionName" prefWidth="108.0" sortable="false" text="ACTION NAME" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="testData" prefWidth="109.0" sortable="false" text="TEST DATA" />
         </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
      <GridPane prefHeight="42.0" prefWidth="579.0">
         <children>
            <Button fx:id="go" layoutX="261.0" layoutY="20.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="32.0" text="Go" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
            <TextField fx:id="url" layoutX="97.0" layoutY="20.0" prefHeight="32.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="20.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Label layoutX="56.0" layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="32.0" text="URL" AnchorPane.topAnchor="24.0" GridPane.halignment="RIGHT">
               <GridPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="5.0" />
               </GridPane.margin>
            </Label>
         </children>
         <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="101.0" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="46.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="515.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="483.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" maxWidth="177.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="50.0" />
         </columnConstraints>
         <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
         </rowConstraints>
      </GridPane>
      <Button fx:id="saveButton" layoutX="663.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#save" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="32.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="15.0" />
      <Button fx:id="clear" layoutX="634.0" layoutY="5.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clear" prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="32.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="55.0" />
      <ProgressIndicator fx:id="progress" layoutX="565.0" layoutY="1.0" progress="0.0">
         <padding>
            <Insets top="10.0" />
         </padding>
      </ProgressIndicator>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes, can you please include it in your question. Normally, this can be achieved by binding the height and width of the TableView with the container of it. Moreover, it can also be achieved by setting the Hgrow and Vgrow for the same.

Comment: Updated the question. I tried wrapping the table in a grid pane as well. Didnt work.

Comment: I missed what you said about `inspect element`. For creating something similar to inspect element of the browser, you will have to use a draggable layout. The container should be a StackPane, so that the `container` can be placed on top of other children.

Comment: I wrapped tableView in a stackPane. Still I'm not able to drag it up. When I place the cursor on the edge of the table, it doesn't even show the "drag icon"

Comment: It won't. Right now, except the stage, nothing else is /should be draggable. You need to enable it on them as I have already mentioned.

Comment: how can I enable it on table? there is no setResizable() method also

Comment: Have you looked into splitpane?

Comment: Ah how could I not think of SplitPane!!! Thanks Uluk :)